# Which specific SQL Server feature installs the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll?

Tags: sql-server

I have a legacy 3rd party application that stopped working when I uninstalled SQL Server. I have since discovered this application requires the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll to be installed on the server.

I could not figure how to only get this dll installed, so I re-installed SQL Server and checked off several features.

How can I tell which feature actually installs the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

**Client Tools SDK** installs the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll

This was discovered by using trial and error. Checking off and adding one feature at a time.